# Devise Gem - How do I clear the configuration values from cache

Tags: devise

I am using devise gem for my rails app. Whenever I try to update the settings like max. number of attempts, Password Regex, Lock Strategy etc. I am forced to restart the server, as otherwise the changes do not take effect. This implies that these values are being cached. What is an efficient way to remove cached values in devise?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `app/config` folder loads only once during server boot.

Trying to hack won't make your life easier.

(though I want to know if it is possible)